# Datatable não popula objeto? JSF

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, hibernate, jpa

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma `DataTable` que é populada com entidades do tipo `Login` que pertence a `Usuario` como relacionamento.

Um botão chamado `Add Login` chama o metodo `addLogin()` de `Login` e uma linha é adicionada na tabela com campos para popular `Login.user` , `Login.pass`, `Login.mac` e `Login.Plano`.
`Plano` já tem que ser persistido anteriormente no banco de dados para que uma lista seja exibida com `selectOneMenu`.

O que acontece é que quando se adiciona mais de um `Login`, apenas o primeiro é populado com a referencia de `Plano` os outros acusam um erro pois o mesmo não pode ser `null`.

[image: Erro quando tenta persistir]

Login

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user"))
public class Login implements Autenticavel{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
private Usuario usuario;

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
private Plano plano;

@NotNull
private String user;

@NotNull
private String pass;

private String mac;

//GETTERS E SETTERS
}
```

Usuario

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "rg"))
public class Usuario implements AbstractEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 150)
@Pattern(regexp = "[^0-9]*", message = "Não deve conter números")
private String nome;

@NotNull
private String cpfCnpj;

@NotNull
private String rg;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataNascimento;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Contato contato;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Endereco endereco;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
private List<Login> login;

@Enumerated
private TipoPessoa tipoPessoa;

@Enumerated
private TipoPrevilegio previlegio;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
private List<Cobranca> cobranca;

// GETTERS E SETTERS

public void setLogin(List<Login> login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public void addLogin(Login login){
    if(this.login == null)
        this.login = new ArrayList<Login>();
    this.login.add(login);
}

public void addLogin(){
    this.addLogin(new Login(this)); 
}

public void removeLogin(Login login){
    if(this.login.contains(login))
        this.login.remove(login);
}
}
```

View

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
            template="WEB-INF/templates/default/main.xhtml"
            xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
<ui:define name="content">                        
    <h1 class="page-header "> <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active">Inicio</li>
    </ol>
    <h:form>
    <b:messages styleClass="messages"
           errorClass="invalid" infoClass="valid"
           warnClass="warning" globalOnly="true"/>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">
           <h:dataTable id="tabelaLogin" value="#{testController.usuario.login}" var="l"
              styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <h:column>
                 <!-- column header -->
                 <f:facet name="header">Usuário</f:facet>
                 <!-- row record -->
                 <b:inputText id="user" value="#{l.user}" />
              </h:column>
              <h:column>
                 <f:facet name="header">Senha</f:facet>
                 <b:inputText id="pass" value="#{l.pass}" />
              </h:column>
              <h:column>
                 <f:facet name="header">MAC</f:facet>
                 <b:inputText id="mac" value="#{l.mac}" />
              </h:column>
              <h:column>
                 <f:facet name="header">Plano</f:facet>
                 <b:selectOneMenu id="plano" name="plano" value="#{l.plano}" converter="planoConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{planoController.findAll()}" var="pl" itemLabel="#{pl.nome}" itemValue="#{pl}"/>
                 </b:selectOneMenu>
                 <h:message for="plano" errorClass="invalid" />
              </h:column>
              <h:column>
                 <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                 <b:commandButton action="#{testController.usuario.removeLogin(l)}" value="Apagar" look="danger" />
              </h:column>
           </h:dataTable>
           <b:commandButton value="Add Login" actionListener="#{testController.usuario.addLogin()}"  update="tabelaLogin" look="success" />
           <b:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{testController.salvar()}"  update="tabelaLogin" look="success" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 3):

Problema resolvido!
Descobri que o problema estava na biblioteca BootsFaces, ao alterar o `<b:selectOneMenu />` para `<h:selectOneMenu />` tudo funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Uma dica, bootsFaces tem muitos problemas, tome cuidado com essa biblioteca.

Comment: Obrigado! Ficarei atento.

Answer (score 2):

brother, já tentou adotar uma strategy ao Id?
//exemplo
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
// no caso de vc estar usando um BD mysql.

ps.
vc poderia adicionar seu arquivo persistence.xml para melhorar o entendimento de sua configuração.

Comment: Defini a strategy, porém isso não resolveu.
Acredito que para resolver esse problema, terei que para cada objeto do tipo Login, fazer com que os campos aparecam dinâmicamente com o jsf.